# How to union 2 left outer join queries?

Tags: mysql

I want to combine these below 2 queries as one single query.

I have a query for residence that is booked.

```
SELECT some coluns
FROM residence r 
JOIN project p ON p.ProjectId = r.ProjectId     
LEFT OUTER JOIN residencetype rt ON r.ResidenceTypeId = rt.ResidenceTypeId    
LEFT OUTER JOIN entity_milestone em ON (r.`Status`='BOOKED' AND        em.ResidenceId = r.`ResidenceId`)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN milestone m ON (em.`MilestoneId`=m.MilestoneId)  
 LEFT OUTER JOIN (builder_prospect bp ON r.builderProspectId = bp.id)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN (builder_prospect bp ON r.builderProspectId = bp.id)
 WHERE r.ProjectId =77 AND r.status='BOOKED';
```

And I have the query for residence that is not booked.

```
SELECT some coluomns
FROM residence r 
JOIN project p ON p.ProjectId = r.ProjectId  
LEFT OUTER JOIN residencetype rt ON r.ResidenceTypeId = rt.ResidenceTypeId  
LEFT OUTER JOIN entity_milestone em ON (r.`Status`='AVAILABLE' AND     em.ResidenceTypeId=r.ResidenceTypeId) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN milestone m ON (em.MilestoneId=m.MilestoneId) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN builder_prospect bp ON r.builderProspectId = bp.id
WHERE r.ProjectId = 77 AND r.status='AVAILABLE';
```

How can I combine these queries and make it as one single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [union/union-all](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm). Make sure that the selected some_colums are the same in both the queries in terms of field names and data-types

```
SELECT some_colums, r.status
FROM residence r JOIN project p ON p.ProjectId = r.ProjectId     
LEFT OUTER JOIN residencetype rt ON r.ResidenceTypeId = rt.ResidenceTypeId    
LEFT OUTER JOIN  LEFT OUTER JOIN entity_milestone em ON (r.`Status`='BOOKED' AND        em.ResidenceId = r.`ResidenceId`)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN milestone m ON (em.`MilestoneId`=m.MilestoneId)  LEFT OUTER JOIN (builder_prospect bp ON r.builderProspectId = bp.id)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN (builder_prospect bp ON r.builderProspectId = bp.id)
 WHERE r.ProjectId =77 AND r.status='BOOKED'
UNION
SELECT some_colums, r.status
FROM residence r JOIN project p ON p.ProjectId = r.ProjectId  
LEFT OUTER JOIN residencetype rt ON r.ResidenceTypeId = rt.ResidenceTypeId  
LEFT OUTER JOIN entity_milestone em ON (r.`Status`='AVAILABLE' AND     em.ResidenceTypeId=r.ResidenceTypeId) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN milestone m ON (em.MilestoneId=m.MilestoneId) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN builder_prospect bp ON r.builderProspectId = bp.id
WHERE r.ProjectId = 77 AND r.status='AVAILABLE';
```

Comment: Thank you. When I am running the query I have made sude that all columns in both queries are same in terms of name and datatypes. But I am getting error like                                                   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'union

Comment: Thank you. When I am running the query I have made sude that all columns in both queries are same in terms of name and datatypes. But I am getting error like                                                   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'union

Comment: Make sure you do not have semi colon before end of first query and before the UNION. Is it possible for you to share the columns you are fetching?

Comment: Yeah there was semi colon at the end of 1st query before union. after removing that again I am getting similar error                       You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM residence r     JOIN project p ON p.ProjectId = r.ProjectId  LEFT OUTER JOI' at line 1

Comment: This is a rather literal solution :-(

Comment: @Strawberry: Why downvote? It has helped the OP. The question asked itself was how to UNION two queries!

Comment: @Natraj. Happy to help. You can accept as answer by clicking the grey tick mark next to this answer. Thanks!

Comment: No. The question was how to *combine* two queries.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this Stack over flow. Its right one. I should give u credit.

Comment: @Strawberry: Well, union also used for combining two queries. Refer docs here <http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm>

Comment: But In my case In wont work because at inner join i have 2 diffrent joins for 2 status's.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE:**
like this?

```
SELECT r.*
FROM residence r JOIN project p ON p.ProjectId = r.ProjectId
LEFT OUTER JOIN residencetype rt ON 
     ((r.`Status`='BOOKED' AND em.ResidenceId = r.`ResidenceId`) 
      OR (r.`Status`='AVAILABLE' AND em.ResidenceTypeId=r.ResidenceTypeId))
LEFT OUTER JOIN entity_milestone em ON em.ResidenceTypeId=r.ResidenceTypeId
LEFT OUTER JOIN milestone m ON em.MilestoneId=m.MilestoneId
LEFT OUTER JOIN builder_prospect bp ON r.builderProspectId = bp.id
WHERE r.ProjectId = 77 AND (r.status = 'AVAILABLE' or r.status = 'BOOKED')
```

**UPDATE2:**
Sorry, `r.status in (...)` will not work!

Comment: But I have 2 conditions like status booked and status available. If i use IN Then I am applying only one condition for 2 status.